# Incrementing a volatile in C++20 with operations on volatile being deprecated

Tags: c++, deprecated, volatile, c++20

C++20 deprecated some certain operations on `volatile` types (following [P1152](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1152r3.html)).

The following code, that was valid prior to C++20:

```
void busyLoop(std::size_t count) {
  for (volatile size_t counter = 0; counter < count; ++counter);
}
```

now generates a deprecation warning:

```
warning: '++' expression of 'volatile'-qualified type is deprecated [-Wvolatile]
```

Changing the `++` to `+=` or to `counter = counter + 1` doesn't help, as the problem seems to be with calculating a new value based on a volatile type.

**How can the above code be adjusted to the new C++20 rules?**

Comment: Have you checked that the `volatile` is really needed to begin with? I've seen (and made) plenty of busy-waiting loops in my days, but never seen (or needed to use) `volatile`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is just a minimal example to show the deprecation done in C++20. Anyway, specifically for this exact case: [without volatile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c4d58f318fd8d85) = 2µs, [with volatile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6497e0fd13b77234) = 27779µs, also there is a change in the [generated assembly in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eWsqzT) though the time is less affected for some unknown reason.

Comment: From a standards perspective, there's' nothing to adjust. "Deprecated" means "**might** go away in the future". Code that was valid before the deprecation is still valid, and its meaning has not changed.

Answer (score 5):

The point of deprecating these operations is to make it clear that `volatile` variables are not atomic in any way and should not be expected to be manipulated atomically. Therefore, for any *actual* code using `volatile`, you need to read the value into a local, manipulate that local copy, and then write the value back to the `volatile` value.

This access pattern is designed to mimic what the committee hopes to codify into a function-based interface that would (maybe?) replace `volatile` entirely at some point. That is, `volatile` becomes a way you access a memory address at load and store times; it wouldn't be an intrinsic property of an object.

---

Note that [C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1023) will "de-deprecate" some compound operations on `volatile` objects. However, [the change only applies to bitwise operators](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2327r1.pdf). The other compound operations are still deprecated, but not as of yet removed.

Comment: Kinda horrible - considering that using C++ for actual down-to-the-metal programming offers a lot of extra safety, now they are actively taking that away by removing basic functionalities without any replacement.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf: "*without any replacement*" There are replacements: `varname = varname + 1;` is equivalent to `++varname`. That may make it difficult to be concise, but `volatile` usage isn't the most common part of even "down-to-the-metal programming".

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting replacement. Why is that better? It seems to me, to fix some misconceptions (volatile/atomic) in high level C++ programmers' minds they are taking away valid tools from low level/HW programmers.:( Maybe I'm just not smart enough to know what is the right solution, but when most HW manufacturers driver libraries are full of volatile stuff, I can't just rewrite them all. (ATOMIC_SET_BIT uses SET_BIT which is (REG) |= (BIT), btw some processors have instructions for |= which doesn't read, while R=R|B would.) Hopefully C++23 will fix this, I don't want to disable warnings.

Comment: @NicolBolas `++varname" can not replace `varname |= BIT_FLAG` - which they removed. And as OP stated - `++varname`  was deprecated in C++20 - aka they want to remove even what you say is the replacement.
And this is a serious problem cause that alone is one thing that makes using C++ for to-the-metal programming a lot less appealing (if not downright impossible to use)

Comment: @ABaumstumpf: I don’t know what you mean. ‘varname = varname + 1’ is not deprecated or removed. And the bitwise operators were undeprecated. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

While incrementing the `volatile` as seen in the question, is deprecated in C++20, you can increment a non-volatile type and assign the result back to the `volatile` type.

The following [code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdd9e2c7248472c4) is valid in C++20:

```
void busyLoop(size_t count) {
  size_t i = 0;
  for ([[maybe_unused]]volatile size_t counter = 0; i < count; counter = i, ++i);
}
```

Comment: This makes `counter` get the wrong value. That is, it gets a different value from what the original code would have gotten. If `volatile` really matters in this example for some reason, then the receiver of the `volatile` value would be getting values in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

`counter=counter+1` is **correct** (to the extent that this code is desirable at all).  The warning for it is a GCC **bug**: it’s supposed to warn only for things like `reg=vol=1;` which might or might not assign 1 to `reg`.  (Even writing `void(counter=counter+1)` doesn’t help.)

Comment: Trying to search gcc's bugzilla couldn't find if a bug was submitted on that. Do you know if there is a bug already opened or should I open one?

Comment: @AmirKirsh: I haven’t looked.  I know only that it’s specific to the `for` case; it doesn’t warn on a standalone statement.  Presumably it is failing to recognize that context as a discarded-value expression.

Answer (score 0):

We can use lambda as iteration expression to get one-liner drop-in replacement for `operator++`:

```
void busyLoop(size_t count) {
    for (volatile size_t counter = 0; counter < count;
        [](auto& v) { auto t = v; v = t + 1; } (counter));
}
```